# How can I properly open and close a modal in jQuery using append() and remove()?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 thumbnails with some text. Clicking on a thumbnail will open a modal. I need to

1) add the modal using append();

2) add an "X" to use it for closing the modal(could be added with append seperately, i just added it in 1 line of code). Closing the modal needs to be done with remove();

3) the modal should be able to be re-opened.

**Tutor gave the following piece of code we had to work with**

```
$( ".thumb" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stops the default action of an element from happening
    if ($(this).hasClass( 'open' )) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        // js when modal is closed 
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        // js when modal is open 
    }});
```

This is the code I had tried. Totally flawed and I have no idea what to do cause i am new to jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="thumb-1" class="thumb">
      <img src="img/turtle.png" alt="turtle">  
        <div class="bottom-content">
            <h2>Consectetur Amet Ligula Bibendum</h2>
            <p> Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="thumb-2" class="thumb">
        <img src="img/reef2.png" alt ="reef"> 
        <div class="bottom-content">
            <h2>Amet Bibendum Ridiculus Sit</h2>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="thumb-3" class="thumb">
        <img src="img/reef.png" alt="more reef"> 
        <div class="bottom-content">
            <h2>Euismod Ridiculus</h2>
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. </p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    animation-name: openmodal;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    display: none;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 1% auto;
/*    padding: 20px;*/
    width: 550px;
    height: 722px;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.close-modal{ 
    float: right;
    font-size: 4em;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

.close-modal:hover {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**My attempt on the jQuery**

```
     $('#wrapper').append('<div class="modal"> <div class="modal-content"> <span class="close- 
      modal">&times;</span> </div> </div>');

    $('.close-modal').on('click', function() {
        $('.modal').remove();       
    })

$(".thumb" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if ($('.modal').hasClass('open')) {
        $('.modal').removeClass('open');

    } else {
        $('.modal').addClass('open');
    }});

});
```

Could someone also tell me if my approach for the `$(".thumb" ).click(function(event) {...`  is properly done, or does it has to be written totally different too?

Comment: Might consider using `.after()` to append the modal after the wrapper. Do you see any errors in Console?

Comment: You don't need the if-open remove-open else add-open -- you can use jQuery's _[toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)_ `$('.modal').toggleClass('open');`

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes.

1. Your JavaScript had an extra closing brace and parenthesis, so I removed those.
2. Instead of adding the modal HTML on load, I changed the logic so that it's added on demand.
3. For the close button to continue to work, I changed the click event so that it's not dependent on the element existing in the DOM at the time the click event is declared.
4. I commented the `height`/`width` in `.modal-content`.
5. I made your `span` close button into an HTML button. This is an accessibility improvement. Also note the use of `aria-label` so screen readers can make sense of what the button should do.
6. Finally, for readability, I changed the HTML creation into an ES6 string literal.

Accessibility issues:

1. Change the thumbnail links with `href="#"` into `button`s. *Buttons do things; links go places*.
2. Add a keyboard event listener for the escape key, which should close the modal if it's opened. This is also an accessibility concern.

```js
function addModal() {
  $('#wrapper').append(`
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
    </div> 
  </div>
  `);
}

$('body').on('click', '.close-modal', function() {
  $('.modal').remove();
})

$(".thumb").click(function(event) {
  if (!$('.modal').length) {
    addModal();
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('.modal').hasClass('open')) {
    $('.modal').removeClass('open');

  } else {
    $('.modal').addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation-name: openmodal;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 1% auto;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  /*   
  width: 550px;
  height: 722px; 
  */
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.close-modal {
  float: right;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: white;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}

.close-modal:hover {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="thumb-1" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/turtle.png" alt="turtle">
    <div class="bottom-content">
      <h2>Consectetur Amet Ligula Bibendum</h2>
      <p> Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="thumb-2" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/reef2.png" alt="reef">
    <div class="bottom-content">
      <h2>Amet Bibendum Ridiculus Sit</h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="thumb-3" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/reef.png" alt="more reef">
    <div class="bottom-content">
      <h2>Euismod Ridiculus</h2>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taerdzw5/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using jQuery UI Dialog. It has a Modal function and with a small tweak, you can theme it like a fancy box. It already has a lot of the functionality you're looking for.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1hus9vcn/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="thumb-1" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/turtle.png" alt="turtle">
    <div class="bottom-content">
      <h2>Consectetur Amet Ligula Bibendum</h2>
      <p> Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="thumb-2" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/reef2.png" alt="reef">
    <div class="bottom-content">
      <h2>Amet Bibendum Ridiculus Sit</h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="thumb-3" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/reef.png" alt="more reef">
    <div class="bottom-content">
      <h2>Euismod Ridiculus</h2>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pale {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
}

.clear {
  background: transparent;
}

.no-show {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function makeModal(cnt, t) {
    var dlg = $("<div>", {
      title: t
    }).html(cnt);
    dlg.dialog({
      classes: {
        "ui-dialog": "clear",
        "ui-dialog-titlebar": "pale",
        "ui-dialog-content": "clear",
        "ui-dialog-buttonpane": "no-show",
        "ui-dialog-buttonset": "no-show"
      },
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      width: 550,
      height: 722,
      show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 300
      },
      close: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
      }
    });
  }

  $(".thumb").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).find("img");
    makeModal(i.prop("outerHTML"), i.attr("alt"));
  })
});
```

See More:

- https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation
- https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/